# How do complain about a post closed for the wrong reason

Tags: discussion, performance

[Best way to stress test a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340564/best-way-to-stress-test-a-website)

I was looking for ways to stress test a website, and saw the question was closed as a duplicate.  However the article said it was a duplicate of a question only for Microsoft specific websites.  Apparently the person closing the article thinks the internet is a subset of microsoft technologies (bet microsoft would love that).

I hope that stack overflow allows questions like these (that do not ask for opinions).  Clearly the person closing the article was biased towards microsoft.

Comment: We have a meta site for this sort of thing, but I wouldn't bother as your premise is off. The question says: _I'd like to be able to simulate heavy traffic on my testing server so that I can work out if the production server is good enough (specifically with iis/asp.net not db performance)._ Not exactly possible to address that without being "biased towards Microsoft"...

Comment: This type of question is no longer on topic on Stack Overflow anyway.

Comment: @Pekka웃 which off-topic close reason would you pick in this case?

Comment: @Gimby I'd gravitate towards `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow` even though it's not 100%

Comment: @Pekka웃 really? I'd not have dared to go there, the question manages to successfully dance around directly asking for something like that by leaving the responsibility with the people answering to tell them what they actually need. Based on the answers already given your choice seems logical however...

Comment: @Gimby I see what you mean, but I wouldn't care in a situation like this. The question is clearly off topic as per community standards, we have a limited set of close reasons that SO is giving us, if someone has a problem with a close reason that's not a 100% fit they need to take it up with SO.

Answer (score 3):

[When you get 3k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you can cast reopen votes.

Until then, you *could* comment on the question, explaining why you think it should be re-opened.

However, in this specific case, the question is specifically asking *"to replicate a large load on an asp.net web application"*

The reason you provided isn't really valid.

Comment: All you need is 250 rep to vote to (close|reopen) your own questions. Since the OP has twice as more rep, he can cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @dorukayhan: It's not his own question. Ha can't reopen-vote it untill he has 3k rep.